# ETS2: Set waypoint when picking up cargo

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

I've got cargo I'm going to pick up on the other side of Europe. When I accept a job, and before I pick up the cargo, I can't set a waypoint until I pick it up, and no directions are given to get to it.

Is there a way to set a waypoint while you are driving to pick up the cargo?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the GPS should, normally, direct you to the pickup point automatically.

Comment: @DJPirtu It shows the green flag, but not the directions (i.e. the red roads and green arrows)

Answer (score 2):

If you accepted a job from the pause menu's Freight Market, the GPS should automatically be pointing to the pick up point. (The button even say "Set as GPS Destination".) You can also add waypoints to your way, if you want to make detours, but the endpoint should always be the pick up.

However, if you accept a job from a business directly (through the floating green question mark, all you get is a green flag on your GPS and a bouncing arrow above the cargo to be picked up. You can't even put in a waypoint on the map.

*However, this method should never take you to the other side of Europe.* In stead, jobs accepted at a business should always be the pick up point in itself, so there should be no need for a waypoint, unless you decide to take a drive around the block.

As to how you managed it, either there was a bug in the game or you misunderstood something.